# How to show the change between infinite sum and integral?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of integrable functions over $E$. If $\sum_n\int |f_n|d\mu<\infty$, then

$$\sum_n\int f _nd\mu = \int \sum_n f_n d\mu$$

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem and monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The comment about dominated convergence goes a long way, but you could try this alternate tactic. Sums are just integrals with respect to the counting measure. Rewrite it as a double integral, and look into Fubini's theorem.